# Vector field line integral: confusion about sign of dl, order of limits

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals

I have some confusion about simple line integrals of vector fields.
If I want to calculate integral 
$\int_C\underline F\cdot d \underline l$ from point $(1,0)$ to $(0,0)$ in a straight line, then what limits and $dl$ do I use?

My intuition would tell me that I use $dl=-dx$ since the line element is in the negative $x$ direction and I would use limits $1 \to 0$, i.e.
$\int_1^0F_x (-dx)$, where $F_x$ is the x component of the vector field. But this would imply that the integral from $1 \to 0$ would be the same as an integral from $0 \to 1$ since the limits $1 \to 0$ and the $-dx$ give a double negative. This shows that I'm mistaken somewhere as the direction of integration should definitely matter in a general case.

What am I misunderstanding? Should I assume that the line element is independent of the direction and instead only depends on the coordinate system, and so in this 1 dimensional case with the x axis it's always going to be $dl=dx$?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about $dl = -dx$, but the limits of integration would be $\int_0^1F\cdot dx$. The reason for this is that you would parametrize the line from $(1,0)\rightarrow (0,0)$ as $c(t)=<1-t,0>$, which means, $c^\prime (t) = <-1,0>$.

So,
$$\int_0^1 F(c(t))\cdot c^\prime (t) dt$$
which gives 
$$\int_0^1 F_x(c(t)) (-dt)$$

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JEET TRIVEDI's answer. Another way would be to let the equation $d\vec{l} = dx\hat{i}+dy\hat{j}+dz\hat{k}$ be as it is (i.e. with no minus signs when computing a line integral) and to let the limits of integration take care of the direction. In your case, it would be $d\vec{l} = dx\hat{i}$ and with the limits from $1 \to 0$, i.e. $$\int_1^0 F_xdx$$ Source: Example 1.11, Page 52, Chapter 1: Vector Analysis, Book: Introduction to Electrodynamics by DJ Griffiths

Hope this helps!